# Не работает прокрутка scrollTop

Tags: javascript, dom, frontend

Вот так вот я пытаюсь проскролить страницу вниз.

```
document.body.scrollTop = 600;
```

Но это не работало. Пробывала завернуть это в window.onload, тоже не помогло. Потом написала немного кода просто для заглушки чтобы в браузере можно было посмотреть по шагам что происходит и увидела что страничка прокручивается до нужного значения, а потом при окончании скрипта снова поднимается наверх.

Подскажите что нужно сделать чтобы прокрутка работала корректно.
Зарание всем спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Использовать метод scrollTo(x, y);
2. Вместо `body` нужен `window` (по какой-то причине)

   ```js
   window.onload = function()
   {
   window.scrollTo(0, 600);
   }
   ```

   ```css
   body
   {
     height: 4000px;
   }
   ```